# How to use glOrtho2D with moving positions?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-1.x

I'm trying to move the camera based on a player (simple square)'s position (x, y). The scale is relatively small and the character is 0.5f by 0.5f.

How can I focus the camera on the player's x, and y coordinates using glOrtho2D?

I am really confused by how you use left, right, down, and up. It makes absolutely no sense, it apparently defines the screen ratio as well as the position in which it draws?

Any help is EAGERLY appreciated.

I switched from the 3d version (gluLookAt) which was the following:

```
gluLookAt(jake.px, 0.0f, jake.pz + 20, jake.px, 7.0f, jake.pz, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
```

and on Resize

```
gluPerspective(45.0f, ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Comment: `gluOrtho2D(player.x - screenWidth / 2, player.x + screenWidth / 2, player.y - screenHeight / 2, player.y + screenHeight / 2)` ?

Comment: @user2802841 nothing still :/ http://puu.sh/4IxBU/58d4475498.jpg

Comment: you can replace screenWidth/Height with some made up values (just keep aspect ratio same as resolution), ex. if your character is 0.5x0.5 then something like 32.0x18.0 (for 16:9 aspect ratio) should make him visible.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the projection matrix (set by `glOrtho`, `gluPerspective`, etc) should be independent of camera movement.  It functions like the lens on the camera.  Camera movement in legacy OpenGL is accomplished with `glTranslate`/`glRotate` (don't forget `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity();`)